# Get localized strings from main bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

How do i get inside the UITest target localizations from the main Bundle?

```
func localizedText(_ key: String) -> String {
    return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
}
```

I tried accessing Bundle.main but isn't localizing the string. And it seems i can't import the main target of the app to do Bundle(for: ClassName.self).localized...

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use your localized strings in UITests you have to do two things:

1) Add your Localizable.strings file to your UITest target

2) Access the string via the UITest bundle:

```
func localizedText(_ key: String) -> String {
    let uiTestBundle = Bundle(for: AClassFromYourUITests.self)
    return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: uiTestBundle, comment: "")
}
```

Just make sure that you use a class that is part of your UITest target to access the bundle.

Using `Bundle.main` does not work when running UITests because it gives you the bundle of the UITest Runner App instead of the UITest bundle

Comment: So I have to check the UITest target in the right panel of Localizable.strings,isn't? I think also bundle.main is also the test bundle If is the ui test target running it

Comment: 1. Yes you also have to check the UITest target for Localizable.string

Comment: 2. Bundle.main does not work in this case (see addition in my answer)